# When someone asks a question but actually just want to answer it themselves

Tags: questions

Is there a term for when someone asks a question but you know it’s only because they either want you to ask them it back, or they want to answer it themselves?

Hope I’ve explained this properly!

Comment: Could you please tell us a little about what steps you have taken to find a suitable word yourself?  Your description of this type of person is as clear and simple as it needs to be.   Why look for one word, unless you are tring to say something on twitter?

Comment: Is this a rhetorical question?

Comment: I found a word ‘hypophora’ but it doesn’t quite cover what I mean.

Comment: Rhetorical would be where there needs to be no answer I think. Or where the answer is already blatantly obvious.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a word for a question asked despite knowing the answer, but meant to elicit a response for the sake of the audience?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/417054/is-there-a-word-for-a-question-asked-despite-knowing-the-answer-but-meant-to-el) See also [What do you call a question you know the answer to, but you want an answer?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/488857/what-do-you-call-a-question-you-know-the-answer-to-but-you-want-an-answer)

Comment: Neither I’m afraid

Comment: It would be like me saying ‘did you do anything last night’ I don’t actually care about your answer but I want you to ask me because I want to tell you what I did last night.

Comment: You should edit these clarifications into the question as comments can be removed.

Comment: You're describing one example of a *counterfeit question*.